# How to do additional logic on set of System.Windows property

Tags: c#, datagridview

Generically, I would like to add logic to a property change that cannot override.

Specifically, I have extended a DataGridView to provide additional functionality, however now I want to do something when someone changes the ReadOnly flag. I cannot override because its not virtual or abstract, and even if I could the System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView will not do the actions it would normally do (like make each column readonly).  How can I add logic to this property change?

```
class MyDGV : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
{
    ....

    // Cannot override ... This code is totally wrong, but I hope you understand the intent
    // Was hoping to do something similar to an overloaded constructor
    public bool override ReadOnly
    {
         get { return base.ReadOnly; }
         set 
         {
              MessageBox.Show("You set ReadOnly");
              base.ReadOnly = value;
         }
    }
}

public void MyMethod()
{
    MyDGV myDGV = new MyDGV();

    // On this property change I want to perform an action, the same action
    //  anytime a MyDGV changes ReadOnly (like warn the user via MessageBox)
    myDGV.ReadOnly = true;
}
```